# css rotate x deg not being applied via js

Tags: javascript, css, rotation

Trying to rotate an image - if I type rotate: x 180deg; into the debug console it works - but nothing happens when trying to set it via js?

```
setTimeout(() => {
   document.getElementById('look-arrow-img').style.rotate = "x 180deg;";
}, 1000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/SamyH/dne7c18q/6/

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, without the semicolon in quote here "x 180deg;" :

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById('look-arrow-img').style.rotate = "x 180deg";
}, 1000);
```

```css
.centered {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.animate {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.full-screen-flex {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="look" class="full-screen-flex centered fade" style="pointer-events: none;">
  <img id="look-arrow-img" class="animate" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2/2231.png" style="width: 30%;">
  <p id="look-dir" style="padding: 1rem; font-size: 2rem; color: black;"></p>
</div>
```

My previous answer with transform is a clockwise rotation:

```js
   setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById('look-arrow-img').style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
    }, 1000);
```

```css
.centered {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.animate {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.full-screen-flex {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="look" class="full-screen-flex centered fade" style="pointer-events: none;">
  <img id="look-arrow-img" class="animate" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2/2231.png" style="width: 30%;">
  <p id="look-dir" style="padding: 1rem; font-size: 2rem; color: black;"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: rotate is valid property. check at mdn [rotate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/rotate)

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it was the semicolon fault.

Comment: Nice one - that seems to work, but not working inside an aframe component on tick function

Comment: Wrapping the img inside a div then rotating the div is what made it work for me in the end